# shell script syntax error: redirection unexpected during done command

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, awk

So, I'm trying to make a shell script for a class and it basically just performs a few administrative operations. Right now, I'm getting a syntax error on the done command on lines 27 and 45. I feel it might be my use of awk.

```
#!/bin/sh
ps -cefl > userInfo
while [ "$menuOption" != 4 ]; do
    echo "===================================="
    echo "Select a menu option!"
    echo "(1) Ancestry History"
    echo "(2) Who's online"
    echo "(3) What process a user is running"
    echo "(4) Exit"
    echo -n "Menu option:"
    read menuOption
    echo " "
    if [ "$menuOption" -eq 1 ]; then
        echo "The ancestry tree for the current process is. . ."
        echo " "
        PID=$$
        while [ $PID -ne 1 ]
        do
            echo $PID
            echo " | "
            while read PIDS; do
                myPID=$(echo $PIDS | awk '{print $1}')
                myPPID=$(echo $PIDS | awk '{print $2}')
                if [ $myPID -eq $PID ]; then
                    PID=$myPPID
                fi
            done < <(grep $PID userInfo | awk '{printf "%i %i\n",$4,$5}')
        done
        echo " 1 "
        echo " "
    elif [ "$menuOption" -eq 2 ]; then
        echo "Online users:"
        echo "-------------"
        who | awk '{print $1}' | sort -u
        echo "-------"
        echo " "
    elif [ "$menuOption" -eq 3 ]; then
        i=0
        echo "Select a user to see the processes!"
        echo "-----------------------------------"
        while read value; do
            listNames["$i"]="$value"
            echo "$i)${listNames[$i]}"
            i=$(($i+1))
        done < <(who | awk '{print $1}' | sort -u)
        echo -n "Select user: "
        read userOption
        echo " "
        echo "You've selected: ${listNames[$userOption]}"
        grep ${listNames[$userOption]} userInfo | awk '{printf "%-7s %-7s %-7s %-7s %-7s %-7s %-10s %s %s\n",$3,$4,$5,$9,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15}' | sort;
        echo " "
    elif [ "$menuOption" -eq 4 ]; then
        echo "Exiting Script!"
    fi
done
```

Comment: You might want to read about the `select` command in `bash`.

Answer (score 7):

No, it's due to your use of sh as an interpreter. Change it to bash.

Answer (score 4):

The lines causing trouble are:

```
done < <(grep $PID userInfo | awk '{printf "%i %i\n",$4,$5}')
done < <(who | awk '{print $1}' | sort -u)
```

These are using ['process substitution'](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution), which is a feature of `bash` that is disabled when it is run as `sh`.  Since the shebang at the top of the script is `#!/bin/sh`, this causes trouble.  You can demonstrate that it is the problem by running:

```
bash yourscript.sh
```

When you do that, you should no longer get that error; you might get other errors, or it might all work.  When all is fixed, change the shebang to `#!/bin/bash`.